# Exception- Value cannot be null. Parameter name: currentDocumentProducer

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using composite Index to order by 2 fields, one is text and other date.
I have created the composite Index and trying to use the same in the .net application. We also have implemented Paging for the same query using continuation token

The records are coming for the first page, but for second page we are getting the exception

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: currentDocumentProducer

If I order by only one field the paging is working fine. We have checked the Continuation token, both seems to be same except for the order by fields.

```
 var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
                {
                    MaxItemCount = pageSize,
                    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                    RequestContinuation = continuationToken
                };
                IQueryable<T> filter = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink, Query, feedOptions);
                IDocumentQuery<T> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();
                FeedResponse<T> feedRespose = query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The stack trace is as below

> System.ArgumentNullException:    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.OrderByDocumentQueryExecutionContext.get_ActivityId
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.OrderByDocumentQueryExecutionContext.ValidateAndExtractContinuationTokens
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.OrderByDocumentQueryExecutionContext+d__23.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.OrderByDocumentQueryExecutionContext+d__19.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.PipelinedDocumentQueryExecutionContext+<>c__DisplayClass5_0+<<CreateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.PipelinedDocumentQueryExecutionContext+d__5.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextFactory+<CreateSpecializedDocumentQueryExecutionContext>d__3.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.ProxyDocumentQueryExecutionContext+d__15.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1+d__36`1.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)

Comment: Would you update your question with the stack trace from the exception and the line of code that the exception happened on?

Comment: And the SDK version you are using?

Comment: I am using SDK Version 2.6.0

Comment: @NayanaSetty can you double check the SDK version? The stack trace points at version 2.0.0